# Compare two text files and replace the lines containing common words in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, text, comparison, diff

Suppose we have a text file containing a fullpath of a files. And a second text file containing just the same files names but they can be preceeded with other characters.

What I'd like to do is replace the filenames into second file with the fullpaths of them which are in the first text file. How can that be done?

For example;

In textFile1.txt you have got:
[image]

In textFile2.txt you have got:
[image]

I need a 3rd textFile3.txt like this (just made it manually for two of the files, but I need that for all of the files in the tree)
[image]

Comment: Can you please update your question with some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the filenames are unique and the paths do not contain any of the filenames:

```
# Read files
$File1 = Get-Content <file1>
$File2 = Get-Content <file2>

# Process each line
Foreach ($Line in $File1) {
    # Get only the filename for current line
    $FileName = $Line.Split("\")[-1]
    # Replace filename in file2 with the entire line of file1
    $File2 = $File2 -replace $Filename,$Line
}
# Write new content to file2
Set-Content -Path <file2> -Value $File2
```

Note: This is untestet, might contain bugs ;)